# Free Shipping Incentive - "Just € xx,- left till free shipping!"

Tags: magento-1.9, free-shipping

I'd like to show a "Free Shipping" Incentive in the cart so that customers now that they have to add a certain amount to receive free shipping.
I work my free shipping with table rates and not the free shipping module.

I found this script but unfortunately its not really working. Any idea how I can get something like this to work?

```
<?php if ($this->getQuote()->getSubtotal() < 100): ?>
<?php $subtotalamt = $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
<?php $freeshipamt = 100; ?>
<?php $sumtotal = $freeshipamt - $subtotalamt; ?>
<?php Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($sumtotal); ?>
<p>You are just <span>$<?php print ($sumtotal); ?></span> 
away from earning free shipping!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

It should read the Cart Total incl. tax and then just show the difference to the price I define.

Thanks

Edit: I inserted the script in /app/design/frontend/theme/default/checkout/cart_new.phtml (my cart template)
and tried to get it working there. It should then show the sentence:
"You are just $XXX,- away from earing free shipping!"

But unfortunately it is not showing anything at all.

Comment: Whats not really working about it?

Comment: Please edit the question and include: What are you trying (already done), what happens and what did you expect

Comment: Done, hope this is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think your quote object might not be loaded in that scope.

Try this (tested working magento 1.9.0.1);

```
<?php 
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if ($quote->getSubtotal() < 100):
$subtotalamt = $quote->getSubtotal();
$freeshipamt = 100;
$sumtotal = $freeshipamt - $subtotalamt;
Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($sumtotal);?>
<p>You are just <span>$<?php print (number_format($sumtotal, 2, '.', '')); ?></span> 
away from earning free shipping!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but unfortunately it is still showing nothing. Not even the part in the <p>...</p>.

Comment: Could you try it in /app/design/frontend/theme/default/checkout/cart.phtml?

Comment: Unfortunately my theme only uses the cart_new.phtml and not the cart.phtml. I tried cart.phtml but then the page doesn't work at all as there would be more customization need to get it too work. The cart_new.phtml file can be downloaded here: https://copy.com/noSdVaJ3uwWEp9kN

Comment: Do you see anything if you do var_dump($quote); ?